# NLog convert UTC to Local timezone in Azure?

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-blob-storage

I'm just starting to work with Azure and I'm using NLog to log to an Azure Blob Storage. I finally was able to get that working but now I see that log files are putting a time stamp of UTC. Is there a way that I can format my config file to convert the timestamp to US Central Time Zone?

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           autoReload="true"
           internalLogLevel="info"
           internalLogFile="C:\temp\fallback-log.txt"
           throwConfigExceptions="true">
    
       <extensions>
         <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
         <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" />
       </extensions>
    
       <targets async="true">
         <target
           xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage"
           name="azure"
           layout="${longdate:universalTime=true} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
           connectionString="your-connection-string-goes-here"
           container="logs"
           blobName="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
   </targets>

   <rules>
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="azure" />
   </rules>

 </nlog>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `universalTime=true` from your config ? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source for changing local time-zone in NLog.

Comment: I removed the universalTime=true but didn't have an effect. Ultimately I had to change the timezone in my Azure Storage Container following this and finding the right setting for Central Standard Time. https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/tip-changing-an-azure-app-service-time-zone

Answer (score 0):

Well probably default is the local time of Container UTC ;)

So changing the timezone in the container could be indeed a good way.

If you really not like to do this, you could create a custom layout renderer:

1. register as soon as possible

   ```cs
   // Usage logEventInfo, ${date_cst} - convert UTC to CST
   var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
   NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>
       s.RegisterLayoutRenderer("date_cst", (logEvent) => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(logEvent.TimeStamp, timezone).ToLongDateString())
   );
   ```
2. use in your config `${date_cst}`

See also [NLog - How to write a custom layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer)